# How to use custom video source for Flutter WebRTC

Tags: flutter, webrtc

I'm developing a Flutter app and need to send a custom video stream other than one from the camera through [flutter_webrtc](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_webrtc). Is there any way to achieve this goal? I took a look at flutter_webrtc's documentation, but it seems there's no interface to create [MediaStreamTrack](https://pub.dev/documentation/flutter_webrtc/latest/flutter_webrtc/MediaStreamTrack-class.html) transmitting a custom video stream.

Thanks,

DK

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We just forked the official library and we added a custom parser to create a MediaStreamTrack object from a custom video stream. You can use the function `parseMediaStreamTrack`passing a track from a custom MediaStreamTrack object.
[Here](https://github.com/zwap-in/flutter-webrtc) you can find our forked repository

Comment: Can you give an example of creating a MediaStreamTrack using startImageStream from the Camera package? This provides frames of the "CameraImage" type.
https://pub.dev/documentation/camera/latest/camera/CameraController/startImageStream.html

Comment: please share ur code and usage of that with thanks